# How can I prevent an unexpected Syntax error?

Tags: php, symfony, terminal, console, php-parse-error

I tried to execute this command in the terminal:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

But I get the following error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in /is/htdocs/myhost/www/project/bin/console on line 26
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony4 requires PHP v7.1.3 or higher.

Check your PHP version using `php -v`.

If you have the correct version try running `composer install`. 
This will install any missing dependencies and should fix the error.